# Route and controller not working properly in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5

I am working in a classroom project in Laravel. When I insert data that time my another route not working. but when I changed route to reverse that time my another route works and first one not work.

Here is my route:

```
Route::get('/class',[
'uses'=> 'classroom@getclass',
'as'=>'class',]);
```

another one:

```
Route::post('/class', [
'uses' => 'classroom@showclass',
'as' => 'classdata,]);
```

and i also give the controller:

```
public function getclass(Request $request)
{
    if (Input::has('post_comment'))
    {
        $status=Input::get('post_comment');
        $commentBox=Input::get('comment_text');
        $selectedStatus=Status::find($status);

        $selectedStatus->comments()->create([
        'comment_text'=>$commentBox,
        'user_id'=>Auth::user()->id,
        'status_id'=>$status
        ]);
        Flash::message('Your comments has been posted');
        return redirect(route('class'));
    }
    if(Input::has('status-text'))
    {
        $text=e(Input::get('status-text'));
        $rules = [
        'status_text'=>'required|string',
        ];
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);


        if(Input::hasFile('status_image_upload'))
        {
            $rules['status_image_upload'] = 'image';
            $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
            if($validator->fails())
            {
                $image = $request->file('status_image_upload');
                $imageName = str_random(8).'_'.$image->getClientOriginalName();
                $image->move('status_images', $imageName);
                $userStatus = new Status();
                $userStatus -> status_text = $text;
                $userStatus -> image_url = $imageName;
                $userStatus -> type = 1;
                $userStatus -> users_id = Auth::user()->id;
                $userStatus -> save();
                Flash::success('Your status has been posted');
                return redirect(route('class'));
            }
        }
        else if ($validator->fails())
        {
            $userStatus = new Status();
            $userStatus -> status_text = $text;
            $userStatus -> video_url = $request['video_url'];
            $userStatus -> type = 2;
            $userStatus -> users_id = Auth::user()->id;
            $userStatus -> save();
            Flash::success('Your status has been posted');
            return redirect(route('class'));
        }
```

another one:

```
 public function showclass(Request $request)
{
    $randomnumber = rand(50001,1000000);

    $classrooms = new Classrooms();
    $classrooms->class_name = $request['class_name'];
    $classrooms->subject_name = $request['subject_name'];
    $classrooms->section = $request['section'];
    $classrooms->class_code = $randomnumber;
    $classrooms -> user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $classrooms -> save();
    return view('class', array('class' => Auth::user()) );
}
```

Where is my problem? I tried it many different way. But not fixed the problem.

Comment: Route::post('/class', [
'uses' => 'classroom@showclass',
'as' => 'classdata,]);

At 'as', there is an missing ', did you notice that?
Should be: 'as' => 'classdata'

Comment: Yes i noticed that but still not working ..

Comment: What do you mean by not working?

Comment: now my error is : Undefined variable: posts (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject11\resources\views\class.blade.php) but i used post variable in controller.

Comment: please add your whole controller code and blade code because the code which you have given here does not contain any post variable.

Comment: Please check this link ... here is my full problem... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39081476/route-or-controller-not-working-in-laravel-5-2