# Route or Controller not working in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5

At first i used a route and a controller to post status vedio link upload file comments. This is the route and controller
Here is my route:

```
Route::any('/class',[
'uses'=> 'classroom@getclass',
'as'=>'class',
]);
```

Here is my controller:

```
 public function getclass(Request $request)
{
    if (Input::has('post_comment'))
    {
        $status=Input::get('post_comment');
        $commentBox=Input::get('comment_text');
        $selectedStatus=Status::find($status);

        $selectedStatus->comments()->create([
        'comment_text'=>$commentBox,
        'user_id'=>Auth::user()->id,
        'status_id'=>$status
        ]);
        Flash::message('Your comments has been posted');
        return redirect(route('class'));
    }
    if(Input::has('status-text'))
    {
        $text=e(Input::get('status-text'));
        $rules = [
        'status_text'=>'required|string',
        ];
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);


        if(Input::hasFile('status_image_upload'))
        {
            $rules['status_image_upload'] = 'image';
            $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
            if($validator->fails())
            {
                $image = $request->file('status_image_upload');
                $imageName = str_random(8).'_'.$image->getClientOriginalName();
                $image->move('status_images', $imageName);
                $userStatus = new Status();
                $userStatus -> status_text = $text;
                $userStatus -> image_url = $imageName;
                $userStatus -> type = 1;
                $userStatus -> users_id = Auth::user()->id;
                $userStatus -> save();
                Flash::success('Your status has been posted');
                return redirect(route('class'));
            }
        }
        else if ($validator->fails())
        {
            $userStatus = new Status();
            $userStatus -> status_text = $text;
            $userStatus -> video_url = $request['video_url'];
            $userStatus -> type = 2;
            $userStatus -> users_id = Auth::user()->id;
            $userStatus -> save();
            Flash::success('Your status has been posted');
            return redirect(route('class'));
        }
}


return view('class',[
'posts'=>status::orderBy('id','DESC')->get()
]);}
```

This position its works nice.
But now i face the problem when i use another route and another controller.
Here is my problem route:

```
Route::post('/class',[
'uses'=>'classroomdata@showclassdata',
'as'=>'createclass',]);
```

And my controller:

```
 public function showclassdata(Request $request)
{
    $randomnumber = rand(50001,1000000);

    $classrooms = new Classrooms();
    $classrooms->class_name = $request['class_name'];
    $classrooms->subject_name = $request['subject_name'];
    $classrooms->section = $request['section'];
    $classrooms->class_code = $randomnumber;
    $classrooms -> user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $classrooms -> save();
    return view('class');
}
```

At this moment my problem is data inserted.I have an error that error is: Undefined variable: posts (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject11\resources\views\class.blade.php)
Why i face that issue ?

Comment: Have a look at your class.blade.php, there's an undefined variable: posts as stated

Comment: Yes but i think there is no problem.. coz at this moment i also can't give a status. but at past its works nicely... when i use 2nd route and controller that time i face this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your second comment, you are returning view **without 'posts'** in **showclassdata** method.

**Comparison**

*getclass method:*

```
return view('class',[
'posts'=>status::orderBy('id','DESC')->get()
]);}
```

*showclassdata method:*

```
return view('class');
```

That's why you are reciving the error.

The **solution** is return in showclassdata method your posts with view.

Comment: Unfortunately not, to accept the answer you need to check the checkmark on the left of my answer.